# Android DownloadManager illegalstateexception unable to create directory

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, create-directory

I'm making android app which is using DownloadManager.
I want to download file into folder which I made.
But this sources don't operate.
And happen IllegalstateException.
What can I do??

```
urlToDownload = Uri.parse(URL);
List<String> pathSegments = urlToDownload.getPathSegments();
request = new DownloadManager.Request(urlToDownload);
request.setTitle(Titlename);
request.setDescription("MCPE STORE");
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
                   "/MCPE STORE", pathSegments.get(pathSegments.size()-1));

Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
                   "/MCPE STORE").mkdir();
latestId = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> What can I do?

If you read [the documentation for `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setDestinationInExternalPublicDir%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), you will see that the first parameter is "the directory type [to pass to `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29)". That needs to be one of the constants defined on the `Environment` class, like `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS`. You are passing something else, which is not supported.

Comment: What should I do if I want to have downloaded file in my app's special folder? Just download file in a constant folder defined by Environment class and then cut/paste file? any idea?

Comment: @AliBehzadianNejad if I got you right,I did it like this:
 request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, File.separator + folderName + File.separator + filename);

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in your `manifest.xml`

Also if you are using an emulator, make sure you created it with SD card storage. It's NOT created by default.