# Java.Lang.IllegalException At Setdestinationfolder path while downloading image

Tags: illegalstateexception

### IllegalException at destination folder path

[image]

### Here is my code am downloading gif images from url

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String uRl = strings[0];
        DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(uRl);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                downloadUri);
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
                DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                        | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                .setAllowedOverRoaming(false).setTitle("Demo")
                .setDescription("Something useful. No, really.")
                .setTitle("Downloading giphy file")
                .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/IslamicGif", "fileName.gif");
        mgr.enqueue(request);
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Does your app have permission to `write_external_storage` ?
And do these help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/17112536/1168654 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/13056375/1168654 ?

Comment: yes i have add both permissions   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: And you also check that you have permission i presume?
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#make-the-request

Comment: thanks a lot for my help i have get the answer right about you asking :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773348/set-custom-folder-android-download-manager

Comment: I was missing the directory folder properly it was not managed so i got it thank you so much File mydownload = new File (Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+ "/myFolder");

if (!mydownload.exists()){
    mydownload.mkdir();
}

Answer (score 0):

Actually i have not manage the directory path perfectly so the error comes its 
 working with this path now.

```
 File mydownload = new File (Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+ "/myFolder");
    if (!mydownload.exists()){
        mydownload.mkdir();
    }
    String url = sUrl[0];
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    }
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(mydownload.getAbsolutePath(),"Myfile.extension");
    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    manager.enqueue(request);
```