# android download manager - download file into previously created directory

Tags: android, download

I want to save the downloaded file into a custom folder previously created  as :

```
String trainingDirectory =  "swimmer" + File.separator + "trainings";
String trainingsPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + trainingDirectory;           
File trainingSubdirectory = new File(getFilesDir() + File.separator + trainingsPath );
trainingSubdirectory.mkdirs();
```

to store the downloaded file into this directory, I tried to follow the solution given : [Set custom folder Android Download Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773348/set-custom-folder-android-download-manager?rq=1)
writing

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir ( "/trainings", "mydownloadedfile.mp4");
```

In this case , the download manager is creating a  new 'training' directory , not using the one I created previously... 
I tried also to use

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir ( "/swimmer/trainings", "mydownloadedfile.mp4");
```

but in this case an error is raised ( a path with separators is not accepted..)
where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
String directoryPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/swimmer/trainings/"
// ...
request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(directoryPath + "fileName.ext")));
```