# How to give a name to downloading file

Tags: android

I am downloading videos from the server using Android **`DownloadManager`**. I want to give a name to each video myself. By default the name of videos downloadfile-6.bin.

```
String servicestring = Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE;
DownloadManager downloadmanager;
downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(servicestring);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(links.get(0));
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
Long reference = downloadmanager.enqueue(request);
```

Suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set it via `DownloadManager.Request` object using `setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(...)` or `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(...)`. See the last line:

```
request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
       .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
       .setTitle("DownloadTitle")
       .setDescription("DownloadDesc")
       .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/mypath", "filename.jpg");
```

**Sources:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16773944/5250273
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html

Comment: Thanks @Ugurcan Yildirim. It works