# How do i download file with Service

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, android-file, android-download-manager

My goal is to download files with a [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) (please, you may suggest a better option) in the background without having to interact with the app such that a download can be triggered (**startService**) whenever it receives a broadcast that a new text has been copied to clipboard and the text has a downloadable extension.

The implementation below uses [PR Downloader](https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/PRDownloader)(Library) to download the file but the file is not downloaded.

I usually get an Error and i Logged the response.

```
onError. isServerError = false. isConnectionError = true
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.package.name">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        ...>

        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                ...
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        ...
        <service android:name=".DownloadService" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            val clipBoard = getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
            clipBoard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener {
                val primaryClip = clipBoard.primaryClip

                if (primaryClip == null || primaryClip.itemCount > 0 && primaryClip.getItemAt(0).text == null)
                    return@addPrimaryClipChangedListener  
                val serviceIntent = Intent(this, DownloadService::class.java)
                val clip = primaryClip.getItemAt(0).text.toString()
                if (clip.contains(".mp3")) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity","$clip")
                    serviceIntent.putExtra(DOWNLOAD_URL_KEY, clip)
                    serviceIntent.putExtra(DOWNLOAD_FILE_NAME_KEY, getFileName(clip))
                    startService(serviceIntent)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**DownloadService.kt**

```
class DownloadService : Service() {
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        val url = intent?.getStringExtra(DOWNLOAD_URL_KEY)
        val fileName = intent?.getStringExtra(DOWNLOAD_FILE_NAME_KEY)
        Log("onStartCommand. FileName = $fileName Download URL = $url")

        if (url != null)
            downoadFile(url, fileName)

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }
    fun downoadFile(download_url: String, fileName: String?) {
        val dirPath ="/Music Downloader/$fileName.mp3"
        val downloadId = PRDownloader.download(download_url, dirPath, fileName)
                .build()
                .setOnStartOrResumeListener {

                }
                .setOnPauseListener {}
                .setOnCancelListener {}
                .setOnProgressListener { progress ->

                    Log("Progress = ${((progress.currentBytes / progress.totalBytes) * 100) as Int}%")
                }
                .start(object : OnDownloadListener {
                    override fun onError(error: com.downloader.Error?) {
                        Log("onError. ServerError = ${error?.isServerError}. ConnectionError = ${error?.isConnectionError}")
                    }

                    override fun onDownloadComplete() {
                        Log("onDownloadComplete")
                    }
                })
        Log("dirPath = $dirPath, download_url = $download_url, Download ID = $downloadId")

    }
}
```

I have also tried using [Fetch](https://github.com/tonyofrancis/Fetch) but same result - file not downloading.

But i noticed that getting and parsing JSON/Xml file worked with VOLLEY (:) I know it's 2018. I'll move to Retrofit, i promise).

Please, what am i doing wrong? How can i download a file using a service.

**UPDATE**

I Tried running the code in the main activity, and it still didn't work. 
I am testing with android 8.1 and i guess something is wrong with the library PR-Downloader

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        PRDownloader.initialize(getApplicationContext())
        val download_url = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/658687/pexels-photo-658687.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=beautiful-bloom-blooming-658687.jpg"
      download(download_url)
}
fun downoad(url: String, fileName: String) {
        val dirPath = "/File Downloader/" + fileName
        val downloadId = PRDownloader.download(url, dirPath, fileName)
                .build()
                .setOnStartOrResumeListener {

                }
                .setOnPauseListener {}
                .setOnCancelListener {}
                .setOnProgressListener { progress ->

                    Log("Progress = ${((progress.currentBytes / progress.totalBytes) * 100) as Int}%")
                }
                .start(object : OnDownloadListener {
                    override fun onError(error: com.downloader.Error?) {
                        Log("onError. isServerError = ${error?.isServerError}. isConnectionError = ${error?.isConnectionError}")
                    }

                    override fun onDownloadComplete() {
                        Log("onDownloadComplete")
                    }
                })
    }
```

Comment: Sir,try to download file without service after successfully download ...do it with service

Comment: if i understand correctly ...when you copied text in clipboard for example text from facebook "testservice.mp3" then broadcast check if text contains .mp3 and its copied to clipboard ...service trigger on that condition.....am i understand you correctly @Micklo_Nerd

Comment: Yes, clipboard service checks. As it's written in the code above

Comment: your problem is just in download file??

Comment: Yes, the problem is just in downloding the file. but as you suggested above, i tried running it in mainActivity but it seems, i'm not allowed to used the internet when my app is minimized

Comment: i will try it in better way and back to you @Micklo_Nerd

Comment: now, if it has network access before download and it returned true `fun isConnectedToInterNet(): Boolean {
        val connectivityManager = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178729/discussion-between-al-tegani-and-micklo-nerd).

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the problem is your **download_url** , it seems "images.pexels.com" is not allowing connections to their photos. I tested below code (which is a downloader in pure java which i implemented) and I got Connection.refused exceptions. Try your own code with https://html.com/wp-content/uploads/flamingo.jpg or https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Bananavarieties.jpg and see what you will get

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    download().execute("https://images.pexels.com/photos/658687/pexels-photo-658687.jpeg",
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path+"/myFolder/", "pexels-photo-658687.jpeg")
}

class download : AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: String?): String? {
        val url = URL(p0[0])
        val buf = ByteArray(1024)
        var byteRead: Int
        val p = File(p0[1])
        p.mkdirs()
        val f = File(p0[1], p0[2])
        f.createNewFile()
        var outStream = BufferedOutputStream(
                FileOutputStream(p0[1] + p0[2]))

        val conn = url.openConnection()
        var `is` = conn.getInputStream()
        byteRead = `is`!!.read(buf)
        while (byteRead != -1) {
            outStream.write(buf, 0, byteRead)
            byteRead = `is`.read(buf)
        }
        `is`.close()
        outStream.close()
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The situation is that, i don't want to build a custom download manager from scratch. and the pexels url isn't the issue and their url isn't blocked

Answer (score 0):

Use DownloadManager class:

```
private var dm: DownloadManager? = null
companion object {
        lateinit var receiver: BroadcastReceiver
    }
```

call this method inside your onCreate:

```
private fun initbroadCastReceiver() {

        receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
                val action = intent.action
                if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE == action) {
                    val downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0)
                    val query = Query()
                    query.setFilterById(enqueue)
                    val c = dm!!.query(query)
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        val columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)
                        if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c.getInt(columnIndex)) {
                            isDownload = true
                            downloadImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_download_grey)
                            downloadImage.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(baseActivity, R.drawable.circle_background_grey))
                            SQLHelper.updateData(bookEntity.id)
                            showToast("Download completed")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

onClick for Download:

```
downloadImage.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener
        {
            if (bookEntity.isDownload == 0 && isDownload == false) {
                if (Misc.isNetworkAvailable(baseActivity)) {
                    dm = baseActivity.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
                    val request = Request(
                            Uri.parse(EnvironmentConstant.BOOK_DOWNLOAD_URL + bookEntity.id))
                            .setTitle(""Title)
                            .setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(baseActivity,path)
                            .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
                    enqueue = dm!!.enqueue(request)
                } else {
                    showAlertDialog()
                }
            } else {
                alreadyDownloadAlert()
            }
        })
```

Comment: the problem with android DownloadManager is that downloaded files are deleted once the app is uninstalled from API from android 6.0

Comment: actually android creates a folder for downloadManager for particular app and all downloaded files are goes there. But you can change the path of the downloaded files. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773348/set-custom-folder-android-download-manager

Comment: Thanks for the input but check this out -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/26332295/6563022

Comment: you should use this method setDestinationInExternalPublicDir

Comment: with that you can only use specified folders like Downloads, Music and Pictures. You can't create a separate file